# How do I open a visible excel full size?

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, operating-system, subprocess

I am running a python script on both my laptop and home computer with:

```
os.startfile(r'C:\\A file.xlsx')
```

This works great, however I cannot seem to find anywhere on how to make this full size

Any idea on how I can make it full size through python?

I use both Apache OpenOffice and microsoft Excel

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1MPi.png)

Comment: What do you mean 'make it full size'? Are you referring to making the window full sized?

Comment: @AetherUnbound Correct.  I added image, as it launches it like this where as I need full screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to maximize the window with this:

```
import win32gui, win32con, os, time

os.startfile('C:\\Path\To\File.xlsx')
# Wait as long as needed for the file to open, this value can be adjusted as needed
time.sleep(3)
# Now maximize the current foreground window (should be the one we care about at this point)
hwnd = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()
win32gui.ShowWindow(hwnd, win32con.SW_MAXIMIZE)
```

Comment: Will this work for both open office and microsoft.  Hmm... is there a way to wait until file is opened as my laptop is slow meaning script will be slow for both if I have high sleep.

Comment: In the `time.sleep` call, simply change the `3` to be however many seconds your device should wait to maximize the window. It should also work for either editor, as it essentially performs the "double click" action on that file and then maximizes the currently active window.

Comment: But when put in task scheduler, python console will poping up and it will go maximize the python console instead of the excel sheet, anyone can share me ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I did

```
import os
os.system(r'start "" /max EXCEL.EXE ' + path)
```

The "" /max is what makes it full screen. Path is the full path of the file. Make sure that EXCEL.EXE is discoverable from current directory when executing this.